# sending more than one variable with .load in jquery

Tags: jquery

Currently i have one variable (cat) how can i send another one as "CS"?

```
$gallery.load('/public/themes/lbd/js/imagegallery.php', {'cat': cat}, function(){
            $(this).fadeIn(function(){
                $('a.customGal').zoomimage(); 
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$gallery.load('/public/themes/lbd/js/imagegallery.php', {'cat': cat, 'CS': cs}, function(){
```

It's just a regular JavaScript object.

Answer (score 1):

```
$gallery.load('/public/themes/lbd/js/imagegallery.php', {'cat': cat, cs:'cs', anotherVar : 'xyz'}, function(){
            $(this).fadeIn(function(){
                $('a.customGal').zoomimage(); 
            });
        });
```