# sending more than one variable with .load in jquery

Tags: jquery

In relation to the topic posted here:
[sending more than one variable with .load in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335825/sending-more-than-one-variable-with-load-in-jquery)

I have a similar issue, I pass my variables to a php file which then looks to retrieve the variable's values.

(I will just post the main bits for now) My line of code reads:

```
$('#step').load("profile/changealbumcover.inc.php", {'album': album, 'image': image});
```

In my php file i have:

```
$album = $_GET['album']; $image = $_GET['image'];
```

This returns blank variable values so I tried:

```
$('#step').load("profile/changealbumcover.inc.php", {'?album=': album, '&image=': image});
```

This also returns blank variable values.

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Thanks in advance

Wayne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `load` method along with data then `POST` method is used to send the data. I think you should use `$_POST` in your php code to retreive the values. And use the below js this is correct.

```
$('#step').load("profile/changealbumcover.inc.php", {'album=': album, 'image=': image});
```

Comment: You don't include the "?" or "&" characters in the `data` element for a jQuery `load()` action - http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: @Locanos - Sorry that was a copy paste problem I changed it. Please remove my down vote :(

Comment: RESOLVED:

I used the $_POST method in my php file and used the below code to pass the variables

    $('#step').load("profile/changealbumcover.inc.php", {'album': album, 'image': image});

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the data as an Object (inline object).

When you use Objects as a data source, JQuery will send the data as POST data.

In your PHP code just change the $_GET to $_POST, and will probably work.

If you would like to use GET, just pass the data as a string.

Answer (score 0):

To send the variables through `$_GET[]`, use the following, and compile the full URL to call the page:

```
$('#step').load("profile/changealbumcover.inc.php?album="+album+"&image="+image);
```

Comment: Tried that but when i sent more than 1 variable both their values were empty. If I sent 1 variable via the above method it was fine.

Comment: Have you tried checking what the line compiles as using `console.log()` and Firefox/Firebug, Web Inspector/Safari, or similar?
ie `console.log("profile/changealbumcover.inc.php?album="+album+"&image="+image);`